# Setting PDF metadata when exporting with AutoCAD

Tags: autocad, autodesk

I wanted to know if it's possible to set the metadata of a PDF when using the export as PDF function on AutoCAD for a DWG file as I want to be able to add tags to PDF files I generate. I know I can do this manually, but currently, I have an ActiveX macro which generates DWG files and their PDFs for me and wanted to automate the process of setting the metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

When using the `DWG to PDF.pc3` plotter to plot a drawing to PDF, you have access to many options which control the composition of the resulting PDF, but access to metadata is not one of them.

To view the available options, you can navigate to:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD 20## - English\R##.#\enu\Plotters
```

Where `<Username>` is your (Windows) username, and `20##` & `R##.#` are the AutoCAD release that you are using.

Double-click on the `DWG To PDF.pc3` file to open it in the AutoCAD Plot Configuration Editor and then select the `Device and Document Settings` tab.

Here you will find all of the configurable options for the PDF writer - unfortunately, configuring metadata is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to give an update since I think I found a way. Since the metadata of a DWG is passed onto a PDF and the metadata of a DWG can be changed using  (the command herehttps://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-B1AB773D-8EA7-4DA6-95BB-38DAF1F34DEC-htm.html), metadata tags can be added.